# How add integer variable in the date_trunc

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to add my `i` variable in the date_trunc. My `i` variable has value 10. This is a piece of my code :

```
date_trunc('month', now()) - interval 'i  month'
```

error:

```
pq: invalid input syntax for type interval: "i  month"
```

Comment: I realize that Oracle does not support `interval '1 month'`, but Postgres does.  Oracle uses `trunc()` and Postgres `date_trunc()`.  I think you are confusing the databases.

Answer (score 2):

You can use arithmetic:

```
date_trunc('month', now()) - i * interval '1  month'
```